# Access transform to T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, pivot, transform

I have this Access query that I am converting to T-SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8.Outstanding) AS SumOfOutstanding
SELECT dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_88.To_ICJ, q_F_TX_AccRec_8.From_Reference__c, 
       q_F_TX_AccRec_8.[From Account]
FROM dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8
GROUP BY dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8.To_ICJ, 
         dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8.From_Reference__c, 
         dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8.[From Account]
PIVOT dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8.Age 
  In ("Current","30 days","60 days","90 days");
```

So far I have done this in T-SQL:

```
SELECT [To_ICJ],
   [From_Reference__c],
   [From Account],
   [Current],
   [30 days],
   [60 days],
   [90 days]
FROM
(Select Sum(dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8.[Outstanding]) AS [SumOfOutstanding],
    dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8.Age AS [PIVOT_ITEM]
FROM dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8
GROUP BY [To_ICJ],
     [From_Reference__c],
     [From Account],
     Age) AS p PIVOT(
     Sum([SumOfOutstanding]) FOR [PIVOT_ITEM]
 In ([Current],[30 days],[60 days],[90 days])) as pvt
```

But my T-SQL results in these errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'To_ICJ'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'From_Reference__c'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'From Account'.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error message which states that the column name is invalid but there is no indication of what column names might actually be valid. It is therefore impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing 3 columns in your subquery select, Try this

```
SELECT [To_ICJ],
   [From_Reference__c],
   [From Account],
   [Current],
   [30 days],
   [60 days],
   [90 days]
FROM
(Select 
     A.[To_ICJ],
     A.[From_Reference__c],
     A.[From Account],
    Sum(A.[Outstanding]) AS [SumOfOutstanding],
    A.Age AS [PIVOT_ITEM]
FROM dbo.vw_SIMP_EN_F_Tx_AccRec_8 A
GROUP BY A.[To_ICJ],
     A.[From_Reference__c],
     A.[From Account],
     A.Age
) AS p PIVOT(
     Sum([SumOfOutstanding]) FOR [PIVOT_ITEM]
 In ([Current],[30 days],[60 days],[90 days])) as pvt
```

Comment: great @Alexander, works like a charm, know my mistake also now....